# decoder cannot decode input

Tags: coldfusion

i'm getting this error returned when using cfimage to scale an image down to size when a user uploads a large image.  It seems to only throw for larger images.  smaller ones go through ok.  i've not seen much help for the issue perusing google/SO...

i'm running cf8.  here is the code, marking the line it fails:

```
 <cffile action="move" source="#imgVars.fileData#" destination="#imgVars.folder#\#imgVars.newFileUUID#.#listlast(imgVars.fileName, '.')#" />
  <cfset newFile = imgVars.folder & '/' & imgVars.newFileUUID & '.' & listlast(imgVars.filename, '.')>
  <cfif fileexists(newFile)>
   <cfimage action="read" source="#newFile#" name="imageToUpload"><!---FAILURE--->
   <cfif ImageGetHeight(imageToUpload) gt 800 or ImageGetWidth(imageToUpload) gt 600>
    <cfset ImageScaleToFit(imageToUpload, 800, 600, "bilinear")>
    <cfimage source="#imageToUpload#" action="write" destination="#newFile#" overwrite="yes">
   </cfif>
   <cfif ImageGetWidth(imageToUpload) gt 600>
    <cfset ImageScaleToFit(imageToUpload, 600, 600, "bilinear")>
    <cfimage source="#imageToUpload#" action="write" destination="#newFile#" overwrite="yes">
   </cfif>
 </cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isImageFile()` instead of `fileExists()`